# Angular - display table rows with empty values (TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following in a view that is displaying a table of data in a nested ng-repeat.

What I would like is to show only rows with empty cells (`<textarea>`) - when link clicked to apply filter. The text of the link should also change to Show all data', so that when its clicked again it will revert to showing all data.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" ng-click="view.applyMissingValuesFilter(view.missingValuesButtonText)">{{view.missingValuesButtonText}}</a>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Resource Id</th>
        <th ng-repeat="locale in view.resourceGridResources.Locales">
            {{locale ? locale : "invariant" }}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="resource in view.resourceGridResources.Resources">
        <td>{{resource.ResourceId}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="res in resource.Resources">
            <textarea ng-model="res.Value"
                      ng-blur="view.saveGridResource(res)"
                      style="min-width: 300px"></textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried the following locic in controller - just to try and show rows with empty data initally:

```
vm.applyMissingValuesFilter = function (linktext) {

        var results = [];

        var temp = vm.resourceGridResources.Resources;

        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < temp[i].resources.length; j++) {
                if (temp[i].resources[j] === '') {
                    results.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(results);

        linktext === "Display Rows with missing data"
            ? vm.missingValuesButtonText = "Show all data"
            : vm.missingValuesButtonText = "Display Rows with missing data";

    };
```

I am getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
   at listController.vm.applyMissingValuesFilter (listController.js:67)
   at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13275), <anonymous>:4:442)
   at f (angular.js:23481)
   at n.$eval (angular.js:15922)
   at n.$apply (angular.js:16022)
   at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23486)
   at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4430)
   at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4116)
```

If i just do something like `console.log(temp.length)` - it outputs the correct length.

Alternatively is there simpler to accomplish this? I have thought about using regular expression, something like ( `<td ng-repeat="res in resource.Resources" | match: ^$`) but I am sure there is a better way using filters?

Comment: I have update my answer for your last comment which is deleted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your object name is `Resources`, not `resources`.

Kindly change `temp[i].Resources` instead of `temp[i].resources` in your second loop and also you should change this line `temp[i].resources[j]` to `temp[i].Resources[j]`

```
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < temp[i].Resources.length; j++) {
                if (temp[i].Resources[j] === '') {
                    results.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

### EDIT:

Also you may need to change `temp[i].resources[j]===''` to `temp[i].resources[j].Value===''`

Comment: Its working - I had to change to `temp[i].resources[j].Value=== null` - thaks for your help.

Comment: You should try null or empty. @PaoloB

Comment: I have just reversed if - `if (!temp[i].Resources[j].Value)` :)